# I want to get the values in array and pass it to some location

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", "products.xml", false);
     xmlhttp.send();`enter code here`
     xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

     document.write("<table border='1'>");
     var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("productItem");
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         document.write("<tr><td>");
         document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ProName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         document.write("</td><td>");
         document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ProRate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
         document.write("</td></tr>");

     }
     document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

This is my JavaScript coding.. I am fetching the values from XML file..
so i want to get these values from an array and to pass in some other place

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and it's plugin [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)